ZFS filesystem corrupted after deleting old snapshots
I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with ZFS. A few days ago on, I was running out of space, so I deleted a one year old zfs backup to free up 80+GB of space. I didn't really know what I was doing, and when I saw warning messages saying I shouldn't delete this old snapshot because it has "child" snapshots, I deleted them anyway because those "child" snapshots were over a year old.
The computer worked fine that day, and the day after.
However today when I turned on my system and tried to login, I got caught in a login loop. I loaded an earlier ZFS snapshot from GRUB and still the issue persisted. I cannot log into Ubuntu X11, but can on Wayland.
When I log into Ubuntu with Wayland, I cannot access any files, and it says my home folder is empty. I can see shortcuts to programs in the start menu, but none of the programs open. How do I fix my corrupted ZFS filesystem? Is there anyway to recover the data?
The zpool list command gives the following output:
bpool  1.88G  1.71G   168M        -         -    46%    91%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
rpool   920G  83.5G   836G        -         -    13%     9%  1.00x    ONLINE  - 


The zpool import command gives this output (which I have shortened)
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                             1.38G   381M    96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                        1.38G   381M    96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_5un9op                           340M   381M   370M  /boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_80copr                           340M   381M   370M  /boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_8qx30p                           340M   381M   370M  /boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_yjchzg                           388M   381M   388M  /boot
rpool                                             81.2G   810G   192K  /
rpool/ROOT                                        80.5G   810G   192K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_5un9op                          3.15G   810G  10.8G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_5un9op/srv                         0B   810G   192K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_5un9op/usr                       192K   810G   192K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_5un9op/usr/local                 192K   810G   348K  /usr/local

